# Lombok annotations are not generated in .class file

Tags: java, maven, lombok

I'm using inteliJ pro 2020, java 11 , `maven` and `lombok`.

After running `mvn clean install` a jar is generated. When I check a specific class file in the jar that has some `lombok` annotations like `@Data, @NoArgsConstructor, @Setter`, the annotations are missing.

For example :

Original class :

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeName;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Set;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.util.Strings;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@Data
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonTypeName("Bclass")
@Slf4j
public class B extends A{
```

.class file in jar :

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeName;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Set;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.util.Strings;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@JsonTypeName("Bclass")
    public class B extends A{
```

The lombock annotations and imports disappeared.

My current pom settings :

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <compilerVersion>11</compilerVersion>
                <release>11</release>
                <annotationProcessors>
                  <annotationProcessor>lombok.launch.AnnotationProcessorHider$AnnotationProcessor</annotationProcessor>
                </annotationProcessors>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
......
<dependencies>
.....
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.8</version>
        </dependency>
....
```

Solutions that I tried :

- Enable annotation processing in the compiler settings.
- Use  and  in the build section in the pom.xml .
- Remove the annotationProcessor from the pom.

My goal is to create a jar of this project and import it into another project. The problem is that when I import the jar to another project, all lombok annotations are missing and I can use get and set methods..
any suggestions ?

Comment: If you add in your code `new B()` or `b.getXYZ()` what happens? Do you have compilation errors?

Comment: No. Everything works fine. The problem is when I try to import the jar to another project..

Comment: Lombok annotations are not supposed to show up in compiled code. The whole point of lombok is to generate boilerplate code but to make the compiled bytecode not look like it. The reason for that is `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)` in the source code of lombok's annotations.

Comment: @f1sh are u sure ? so it means that code that was generated via lombok cant be used by other java applications ? Shouldnt those methods (getter,setter) should be created during compilation time ?

Comment: Why exactly do you need the annotations? In general, the annotations are only used by the lombok processor to generate/modify existing code. When you look at the [lombok API](https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/package-summary.html), you will see that most annotations have a `RetentionPolicy` of  [`SOURCE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html#SOURCE) and are thus discarded after compilation.

Comment: @JeyJ of course it can. The getters, setters etc should show up in the compiled .class file, they were generated. But the lombok annotations are not in the class file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lombok annotations are not supposed to show up in compiled code. The whole point of lombok is to generate boilerplate code but to make the compiled bytecode not look like it. The reason for that is the RetentionPolicy in the declaration of lombok's annotations:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
```

means that the annotation will be removed after the compilation step and not be part of the bytecode.